# Filter records by date to retrieve the last 7 days

Tags: mysql

I'm kinda new to SQL and am trying to create a query that will count an entry if it matches several parameters. One of those is that it has to have been entered within the last 7-days, I have the rest of the query parameters running fine but the moment I add the AND for the date range it breaks. can anyone assist? Here's my query, the date field is pvs.last_reading and the format is 2019-06-24 16:20:00.

```
SELECT  count(*) as criticalCases
  FROM patient_vitals_state pvs
  INNER JOIN user u on u.uuid = pvs.patient_uuid
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT pc.clinic_uuid FROM patient_clinics pc
      WHERE pc.clinic_uuid IN (?) AND pc.patient_uuid = u.uuid
    )
  AND pvs.avg_sbp >= 181
  AND pvs.last_reading BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: Why does the query as written not produce the desired result? What does "as soon as I add the date check 'it breaks'" actually mean?

Comment: Right now if I remove the last AND the query runs just fine and returns several results. If I add it it returns 0 when it should return 1.

Comment: Here are all the cell values it should be looking at.
2019-06-24 16:20:00,
2019-06-01 19:00:00,
2019-06-24 14:00:00,
2019-06-20 18:25:00
their is another field pvs.avg_sbp that is being evaluated and only the freading on the first row matches the criteria.

Comment: the SQL looks sound; honestly my guess is that you have a boundary condition; you can test this by changing '7' to, say '14', or '90', or '365' and seeing how many results you get; that will show you that the SQL is okay, then you can focus on the data;  because the data is dates, you need to consider things like server time (not necessarily the same as your desktop's time), timezone, etc.

Comment: "only the freading on the first row matches the criteria"  ...  what do you mean my this?  `freading` isn't a criterion in you SQL

Comment: Here's something really weird, if I change the Interval from 7 to 30 it pulls and counts the record for 2019-06-01 but not a record for today 2019-06-24??

Comment: Sorry landru27, that should have bee "reading". basically I have 1 entry in the system. that should be less than 7-days old and have an avg_sbp rating of 181 or more.

Comment: your comment about not returning a record for today reminds me strongly of times when I've run into date boundary issues;  you can start troubleshooting by seeing what the results of `SELECT NOW();` are;  maybe the time on the SQL server is different than what you think it is?  and don't be surprised if tomorrow you start seeing the row for 6/24;  I'm 99.44% confident that you are facing a datetime boundary issue

Comment: Okay so going on the lead I'm dealing with a boundary issue I just ran. `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) as One_Week_Ago`. and the output was, '{ One_Week_Ago: 2019-06-17T12:50:20.000Z }'. That's the correct date so why is it still flipping out?

Comment: notice the time on your one-week-ago result: `12:50`;  the data row you are expecting to see has a time of `16:20`;  thus, on the server running MySQL, `NOW()` is still *before* the datetime of the row you are expecting to see;  furthermore, the `Z` in the time portion of the one-week-ago result tells me this disparity has a lot to do with timezone assumptions

Comment: Thanks everyone I figured it out, instead of just plain NOW() I had to run the filter as BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) to account for the TimeZone difference.

Comment: I've transformed our conversation in these comments into an answer; precisely how to deal with this depends on several factors -- too many to offer specific steps -- but there is ample reading material out there on this topic (timezones in database columns) and the best approach will depend on your exact situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a datetime boundary issue.  The SQL is sound.  Per our conversation in the comments, the data row you are expecting to see has a datetime of:

```
2019-06-24 16:20:00
```

but based on your one-week-ago query the datetime on the server (as of when I am writing this) is closer to:

```
2019-06-24 12:50:20
```

Thus, `NOW()` is *before* the `patient_vitals_state.last_reading` value, and the SQL is in fact doing exactly what would be expected : it is excluding a result whose `last_reading` is outside of the `BETWEEN` parameters.

The `Z` in the result you posted, `One_Week_Ago: 2019-06-17T12:50:20.000Z` tells me primarily that the MySQL server is storing datetimes in UTC, but you are basing your expected results on your own local time.  Possibly, you are also inputing times using your own local time, but unknowingly they are being stored in UTC, thus representing a point in time different from what you really intend.

Timezone issues are a very common class of problems when dealing with dates and times; the timezone being used for a database column is one particular aspect of this general problem.

To solve this, you need to sync up how datetime data are being input into, stored in, and fetched from the database.  There is a lot to read on this topic -- too much to post in an SO answer.  But hopefully this explains the source of the problem, and guides you to the reading that you need to do to understand the fundamental issue.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
SELECT  count(*) as criticalCases
  FROM patient_vitals_state pvs
   JOIN user u 
    on u.uuid = pvs.patient_uuid
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT pc.clinic_uuid 
     FROM patient_clinics pc
      WHERE pc.clinic_uuid IN (?) 
    AND pc.patient_uuid = u.uuid
    )
  AND pvs.avg_sbp >= 181
  AND pvs.last_reading BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
    AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: um, ... I see how adding a day to your date range gets you the data you want, but that solution is likely to fail you at some point; MySQL offers facilities for dealing with the disparity between server timezone and client timezone; I urge you to read up on the topic, because more robust solutions are available; for example, you in fact have future datetimes in your data -- do you really want to store as a last_reading value a point in time that has not occurred yet?

Comment: I want to make my plea even stronger :  think about what it means that you need to fudge the meaning of what "now" means in order to get the data you want; and from the table names it sounds like we are talking about healthcare data; you really need to change your data or deal directly with the timezone disparity -- not look into the future to capture data that is suppose to be in the past;  please, please, please understand how this could go horribly wrong for someone who thinks the results actually mean "as of right now"